# Prove that $K=k(\alpha)$

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Prove:

If K\k is a Galois extension and $\alpha \in K$ with  $\sigma(\alpha)\neq \alpha$ for all $\sigma \in Gal(K,k)\backslash \lbrace id_K \rbrace$, than $K=k(\alpha)$.

Comment: Roughly, if you hit $\alpha$ with all the $\sigma$s, you get all the missing elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $k \subseteq k(\alpha) \subseteq K$ then $K$ is Galois over $k(\alpha)$, if $\beta \in K$ is and $\sigma$ fixes $k(\alpha)$ then $\sigma =id$ so $\sigma (\beta)=\beta$, this $\beta$ is fixed by all automorphisms over $k(\alpha)$ and $\beta \in k(\alpha)$ since beta was arbitrary, $K=k(\alpha)$

Comment: I do not get why $\beta \in k(\alpha)$. Can you explain this? Appreciate your help!

Comment: Isnt this the definition of Galois, an element fixed under all autos is in the ground field.